# Changing variable inside settimeout inside another function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create reusable function that has settimeout function inside that will change the variable passed to the first function.

```
let variable = true;


reusablefunction = (passedvariable) => {


    setTimeout(() => {

        passedvariable = false;
       // this turns out true for some reason

    }, 1, passedvariable);
  };



// Change value of passed variable (variable) to false after a timeout 

reusablefunction(variable);
```

Comment: With how Javascript works, that can not happen.

Comment: This sounds like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the underlying thing you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Looks like it is no more an X/Y problem to you, because you answered it @T.J.Crowder .. Right?

Comment: @ArupRakshit - I answered the question asked (Y). But while that's probably a bit helpful, I suspect if we knew what the underlying issue is (X), we could probably offer a better solution for it.

Comment: I'm trying to create reusable function that will take varible, run timeout function and change the value of a said variable after some time. Im sure there are some better options to do it, I just didn't figure them out.

Comment: So basically my app has a couple of states. This function suppose to take one of the states and after some time randomly change it either to true or false. Im not sure Im explaining this good enough.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - No, it's not "spot booking." It's answering the question asked. There's no reason to assume nefarious intent here.

Comment: @user1743703 - In that case, passing an object into the function could well be a reasonable way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. When you do

```
reusableFunction(variable);
```

the **value** of `variable` is passed into the function, not the variable itself. The parameter `passedVariable` is not in any way connected to `variable`. That is, you end up with something like this in memory:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| variable: false |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| passedVariable: false |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

You could pass in an object and have the function update a property on it instead:

```
let obj = {
    prop: true
};

let reusablefunction = (passedObject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        passedObject.prop = false;
    }, 1); // No need to pass the parameter here
};

reusablefunction(obj);
```

With that, you end up with something like this in memory:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+              
| obj: Ref55461 |−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+             |
                              |          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                              +−−−−−−−−−>|   Object    |
                              |          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |          | prop: false |
| passedObject: Ref55461 |−−−−+          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Since both `obj` and `passedObject` refer to the same object, you can change its properties via either of them.

---

That said, there may well be a better way to solve the underlying problem you're trying to solve...